# Find an index for a given Point coordinate from an array of Points

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, ellipse

Given an Point array and an arbitrary x,y coordinate, find the **index** for _points that is closest to the given coordinate.

```
PointD[] _points
//create a list of x,y coordinates:
for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfArcSegments + 1; i++)
{

    double x1 = _orbitEllipseSemiMaj * Math.Sin(angle) - _focalDistance; //we add the focal distance so the focal point is "center"
    double y1 = _orbitEllipseSemiMinor * Math.Cos(angle);

    //rotates the points to allow for the LongditudeOfPeriapsis. 
    double x2 = (x1 * Math.Cos(_orbitAngleRadians)) - (y1 * Math.Sin(_orbitAngleRadians));
    double y2 = (x1 * Math.Sin(_orbitAngleRadians)) + (y1 * Math.Cos(_orbitAngleRadians));
    angle += _segmentArcSweepRadians;
    _points[i] = new PointD() { x = x2, y = y2 };
}
```

I'm drawing an ellipse which represents an orbit. I'm first creating the point array above, then when I draw it, I (attempt) to find the point closest to where the orbiting body is.

To do this I've been attempting to calculate the angle from the center of the ellipse to the body:

```
public void Update()
{    
    //adjust so moons get the right positions (body position - focal point position) 
    Vector4 pos = _bodyPositionDB.AbsolutePosition - _positionDB.AbsolutePosition;   
    //adjust for focal point
    pos.X += _focalDistance; 

    //rotate to the LonditudeOfPeriapsis. 
    double x2 = (pos.X * Math.Cos(-_orbitAngleRadians)) - (pos.Y * Math.Sin(-_orbitAngleRadians));
    double y2 = (pos.X * Math.Sin(-_orbitAngleRadians)) + (pos.Y * Math.Cos(-_orbitAngleRadians));

    _ellipseStartArcAngleRadians = (float)(Math.Atan2(y2, x2));  //Atan2 returns a value between -180 and 180; 
}
```

then:

```
double unAdjustedIndex = (_ellipseStartArcAngleRadians / _segmentArcSweepRadians);
while (unAdjustedIndex < 0)
{
    unAdjustedIndex += (2 * Math.PI);
}
int index = (int)unAdjustedIndex;
```

The ellipse draws fine, (the point array is correct and all is good once adjusted for viewscreen and camera offsets and zoom) 
But does not start at the correct point (I'm decreasing the alpha in the color so the resulting ellipse fades away the further it gets from the body)
I've spend days trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here and tried a dozen different things trying to figure out where my math is wrong, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Your assumption that the point on the elipse closest to the given point is at the same angle as from the center of the elipse to the given point is not correct. For this assumption to be correct, you need to first translate the elipse and the point such that the center of the elipse is 0,0. Then you need to scale the elipse (and the point with it) so that the the elipse turns into a circle. Then you can use your angle assumption.

Comment: You're not wrong, and that is exactly what the Update() function is doing, though not to the ellipse, but to the point we're finding the angle for. it's not adjusting for eccentricity since that should be unneeded in this case. the point where the orbiting body is will go through each of the points of the ellipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that _points should be an array of PointD;
This is the shortest way to get the closest point to your array (calcdistance should be a simple function that calculate the euclidean distance):

```
PointD p = _points.OrderBy(p => CalcDistance(p, gievnPoint)).First();
```

Comment: Oops, yes my bad it should be PointD[] _points; an error in clipping only the important bits of the code.

What are the cost differences between a sort on a ~80 to 255 sized point array vs Math.Sin, Cos, Atan?

Comment: Regarding the index, you can convert it to regular for loop and save the min index. About the performance issues, you should measure it. In my opinion, sort cost is less then math functions

Comment: While I would have preferred to find out what was wrong with my code,  this is an easier way to do it. the question hasn't generated any more replies so I'll give this the accepted answer.